# How do you access the elements of an complex enum type in rust?

Tags: rust

For example, consider:

```
#[deriving(Eq, Show)]
struct EventOne {
  x: f64,
  y: f64
}

#[deriving(Eq, Show)]
struct EventTwo {
  x: int,
  y: int
}

#[deriving(Eq, Show)]
enum ComplexEvent {
  A(EventOne, ~str),
  B(EventTwo, ~str)
}
```

I have here a complex enum ComplexEvent that can be either an A, or a B.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
let x = A(EventOne { x: 0.1, y: 0.1}, ~"Hello");
let z = x.EventOne;
```

...but that results in the error:

```
error: attempted access of field `EventOne` on type `union::ComplexEvent`, but no field with that name was found
let z = x.EventOne;
```

Erm... ok, as an array?

```
error: cannot index a value of type `union::ComplexEvent`
let z = x[0];
```

Ok, well to be type safe maybe you need to use match for this?

```
match x {
  A(_, _) => ???,
  B(_, _) => ???
}

...

union.rs:28:3: 31:4 error: mismatched types: expected `()` but found `std::result::Result<(),std::io::IoError>` (expected () but found enum std::result::Result)
union.rs:28   match x {
union.rs:29     A(_, _) => ???,
union.rs:30     B(_, _) => ???
union.rs:31   }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I'm probably just missing the specific syntax you need to get this working, but I can't for the life of me figure it out...

Edit: Removing the => action on the example because it seems to be confusing everyone. Read the question guys! I want to get a *subvalue* from *inside an enum* that already exists, not match() an enum and do a println!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```rust
let x = A(EventOne { x: 0.1, y: 0.1 }, ~"Hello");
match x {
    A(EventOne{x, y}, s) => println!("{}, {}, {}", x, y, s),
    B(EventTwo{x, y}, s) => println!("{}, {}, {}", x, y, s)
}
```

Note that matching like this means that you are moving out `~str` field because it is not implicitly copyable, so `x` becomes partially moved value, which you cannot use further. If you do want to use the value after the match, you can bind `s` by reference:

```rust
let x = B(EventTwo { x: 1, y: 2 }, ~"World");
match x {
    A(EventOne{x, y}, ref s) => println!("{}, {}, {}", x, y, *s),
    B(EventTwo{x, y}, ref s) => println!("{}, {}, {}", x, y, *s)
}
```

In this case `s` has type `&~str`, so you have to dereference it to print it. You will be able to use `x` afterwards, because you are not moving `~str` field out, and the other field is implicitly copyable because it consists of implicitly copyable data.

Comment: +1 I would only change the name of the initial `x` variable to `z` so it won't be hided by the internal one of same name, just to make things clear.

Comment: @pepper_chico, you're right, however, I have noticed that overriding variables from outer scope is idiomatic in Rust. `x` is not supposed to be used inside match arms, so it is safe to leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `match`, as you did in your final example. The error you got there is due to the use of `trace!()` (what is that? My Rust doesn't have it), which has the return type `IoResult<()>` (which is a typedef for `Result<(),std::io::IoError>`), but Rust was expecting your expression to have the type `()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll accept another better solution if one comes up, but the way to do this is:

```
macro_rules! trace(
  ($($arg:tt)*) => (
    { ::std::io::stdout().write_line(format_args!(::std::fmt::format, $($arg)*)); }
  );
)

#[deriving(Eq, Show)]
struct EventOne {
  x: f64,
  y: f64
}

#[deriving(Eq, Show)]
struct EventTwo {
  x: int,
  y: int
}

#[deriving(Eq, Show)]
enum ComplexEvent {
  A(EventOne, ~str),
  B(EventTwo, ~str)
}

#[test]
fn test_lifetime_scope() {
  let x = A(EventOne { x: 0.1, y: 0.1}, ~"Hello");
  let y = B(EventTwo { x: 1, y: 2}, ~"Hello2");
  let mut z:&EventOne = &EventOne { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 };

  match x {
    A(ref a, _) => z = a,
    B(b, _) => trace!("{}", b)
  }

  trace!("Accessed values: {}", z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```rust
use std::rand;
use std::rand::Rng;

#[deriving(Eq, Show)]
struct EventOne {
    x: f64,
    y: f64
}

#[deriving(Eq, Show)]
struct EventTwo {
    x: int,
    y: int
}

#[deriving(Eq, Show)]
enum ComplexEvent {
    A(EventOne, ~str),
    B(EventTwo, ~str)
}

#[deriving(Eq, Show)]
enum Event { EventOne, EventTwo }

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::rng();

    let z:ComplexEvent =
        if rng.gen() {
            A(EventOne { x: 0.1, y: 0.1 }, ~"☺")
        } else {
            B(EventTwo { x: 100, y: 200 }, ~"☹")
        };

    match z {
        A(e, _) => println!("{}", e),
        B(e, _) => println!("{}", e)
    }
}
```